# Absent symmetric key and master key after restoring to new server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2012

I had a SQL database on a previous server, of which I had a master key and certificate creating using the following syntax:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'AReallyReallyReallySecurePassword!!!!!'
CREATE CERTIFICATE CPCertificate01 WITH SUBJECT = 'CP Certificate'
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01 WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CPCertificate01
```

I've done a backup of this database, and now restored it onto a new server (fresh install of SQL Server as well).

When I try to run commands against the database, I get this error:

> **Cannot find the symmetric key 'SSN_Key_01', because it does not exist
>   or you do not have permission.**

However if I run this code...

```
select * from sys.symmetric_keys
```

...I can see SSN_Key_01 listed in the result set.

I also get other errors relating the master key not existing.

Can anyone please guide me as to how I can recreate the encryption settings on the new server without losing any of my data?  I still have access to the old server if required.  Thanks.

Comment: Either you don't have a permission or you have not restored old Service Master Key (SMK) into new database - I think (but can't be sure) that some of old keys/certificates are encrypted using SMK

Comment: How would I 'extract' it first please?  I don't even know what terminology I should be searching for...!

Comment: Start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190337.aspx. "Service Master Key" is term to search. But I have very little experience with SQL crypto; beofre replacing SMK (which may change situation to worse) consider other possibilities.

Comment: Or you should export your keys and certifictes from old server and import into new - SMK is server-wide, your keys are database related. I really don't know precisely, that's why I only comment :)

Comment: I've followed the MSDN article, and will post a new question related to my progress.  This isn't an easy subject...!